# Google Drive API V3 - Some folders with Root Parents show under a different folder in Google Drive UI

Tags: google-drive-api

In C# (Visual Studio 2015), the code, below, lists the folders with 'root' as the parents id.  However, when I go to the Google Drive UI (drive.google.com), some of the folders listed, appear within other, non-root, folders.  I've looked at the properties of those folders in C# and see nothing to indicate the discrepancy. I'm obviously missing something.  Any ideas?

It's possible that I originally created the folders in question in the root and then moved them to the sub-folder, so it's maintaining its original Parents.  Even so, how is the UI positioning them properly, but the API doesn't give me any indication that it should be elsewhere?

```
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
            listRequest.PageSize = 100;
            listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(*)";
            listRequest.Q = " ('root' in parents) and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' ";
            listRequest.OrderBy = "name";
            listRequest.Spaces = "drive";


            // List files.
            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;

            Console.WriteLine("Files:");
            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
            }
            Console.Read();
```

Comment: It could be due to a server propagation issue. How much time has passed since you moved the folders and tried to list them with the API?

Comment: It's been months

Comment: It occurred to me to look at the value of the "WebViewLink" property for these folders. When I used the link to navigate to them, I discovered they were in "Trash".  Then I noticed that the "Trashed" property is True.  There are two non-Trashed folders with the same name and I assumed those were the ones it was pointed at. Wrong assumption.  Sorry for the fire drill.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me to look at the value of the "WebViewLink" property for these folders. When I used the link to navigate to them, I discovered they were in "Trash".  Then I noticed that the "Trashed" property is True.  There are two non-Trashed folders with the same name and I assumed those were the ones it was pointed at. Wrong assumption.

Changed the query value to:

```
listRequest.Q = " ('root' in parents) and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false";
```